# Garbage value in an array where array length and input is defined

Tags: c++, arrays

I am a beginner, and I am trying to learn C++.

For now, all I am trying to do is input 3 numbers, and print them back.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n[2];
    cout << "Enter three numbers" << endl;
    
    for (int j = 0; j <= 2; j++){
        cin >> n[j];
    }
    cout << "Debug " << n[2] << endl;
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++){
        cout << n[i] << "\t" << i << endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Every time I print them, the last value of the array is modified, and I cannot figure out why! For a test input `6,7,8`, the output is in the image below.

[image]

Comment: `int n[2];` gives you an array of length 2. n[0] & n[1] are valid. n[2] is not & attempting to put stuff there can cause bad stuff to happen.

Comment: If you are trying to "input 3 numbers", can you explain why your array has ***only 2 values***? How many values do you expect `int n[2]` to have? Attempting to put three values into an array with two values always results [in demons flying out of your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html), with the observed results!

Comment: Maybe `int n[3];` In an array declaration, the `[2]` indicates the length or number of values the array can contain. Those have indices of `0, 1...n-1`. So, if `n==3`, your array would be declared as `int n[3]`, and your loops would access elements 0, 1 and 2.

Comment: It would be better to post the output as text (in a code block), instead of an image. You may want to read this: [Why not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12149471) In order to post text from the Windows Console, you can select "Mark"->"Select All" and then press the ENTER key to put it into the clipboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `for`

```
for (int j=0;j<=2;j++){
      cin>>n[j];
    
}
```

expects that the array has at least three elements with indices in the range [0, 2].

However you declared an array with two elements

```
int n[2];
```

If you are going to input three elements then the array should be defined as

```
 int n[3];
```